# Using a Raspberry Pi Camera with ROS: raspicam_node vs. cv_camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, ros

I am running a ROS1 robot, on a raspberry Pi, with Ubuntu 20.04. I have a working Raspi V2 camera hooked up. My plan is to identify fiducials.

In the past I've used raspicam_node but that code has not been touched in a while and really is not supported. I don't love it but with a struggle I can get it to work.

I see that cv_camera might be an alternative, but I don't know if I would be trading one set of headaches for another set.

Does anyone have experience with this trade-off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an update and an answer: I now have experience with the tradeoff, and for my use case, I have found [cv_camera](https://github.com/OTL/cv_camera) to be easier to deal with and simpler. It is now my interface to a pi camera in ROS.